# I handed in notice before getting another offer. How do I explain this in interview?

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-change, india

During my notice period I was not able to find a job that best fit my experience and my dream job in my country (India) particularly in my region. Now my notice period is completed, still I am not able to get the job (I've been looking for the last week).

Currently when I attend interviews and employers ask me for the reason for my job change, I am honest with them. However, I feel that this honesty is having an impact on my results at interview. Should I say something else instead? What's the best way to explain?

Comment: Usually you first find a job and then hand in your notice - to avoid this exact situation. Where are you located?

Comment: In Gujarat India,Now I understood that point.

Comment: Hey adb, and welcome to [workplace.se]! As-is, it's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking. None of us know if you'll be able to find another job, or why you haven't been able to up to this point. Is there any chance you could [edit] your question to focus on *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* as explained in our [help/dont-ask]? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok I will update the question

Comment: What are you saying in the interviews about *why* you handed in your notice without having another job?

Comment: Why did you leave your previous job?

Answer (score 5):

In the US employers tend to like someone who is currently working. This is probably true in much of the rest of the world as well.

Taking a peek at your profile, I see references to User Experience and Android. This hints at things like web page layout, app storyboarding, etc.

If you are 'between jobs' in the full time sense, then the first fallback is the 'contractor' role where you work on a time and materials basis.  You might also work 'temp', which is similar in some respects, however the contract is with the temp firm, not with you directly.  Often this starts to look like full time work, with the distinct difference being that they can let you go on almost no notice.

In general, someone in your situation will need to cast a wider net. If someone tells me that they can't find work for a big company developing websites, I suggest that they work on departmental databases (i.e., Microsoft Access) at a local medical clinic or wholesale warehouse.  Anyone that works 'indie' gets used to taking on strange jobs - that comes with the territory. Work like this changes one's perspective pretty significantly, successfully completing it even more so. In general, employers are impressed with flexibility and adaptability.

The value in this is that if someone asks you what you're doing now, you have an answer beyond 'sitting at home emailing resumes'. The work might be ghastly and the pay miserable, but taking on a challenge is better than appearing inactive.

Comment: Here In India we have different situation about company,when you find the job they are interested in why you left or resign your previous/last job instead of experience and expertise of candidate,even if we are ready to work in small amount/percentage of hiking in salary.

Comment: @adb - If you are interviewing employers that are more interested in why you left your last job than they are in your experience and expertise, you're interviewing with the wrong employers. This would be true no matter what country you're in. If this is true 90% of the time, seek out the remaining 10%. You would be better off working independent on performance oriented tasks then trying to take full time work with employers that are sensitive to deference and hierarchy.

Comment: currently I am looking the employers that are really interested in my 3 years experience and expertise in android platform, I always ready to work full time.